# PC won't start at all

Tags: boot

My PC model is Acer M1640, the PC won't start. Here are my tests:

Problem:

- The PC wont even BEEP
- The power lights and fans work normally
- The hard disk spins, and I can hear it working

Things I have tried doing:

- Removing all drives
- Testing all the RAM's (Removed one, tested one, and removed all)
- Cleaning the CPU fan
- Removing the graphics card
- Tried a new battery and PSU disconnection

None of those worked. I have also tried seeing if any wires are loose.

Suggestions and fixes anyone?

Comment: So you don't see any output whatsoever on the screen? And you've tried plugging the monitor right into the motherboard?

Comment: Nope, nothing. No signal.

Comment: Can you confirm that the monitors work? If not this seems like there might have been a short circuit somewhere. Is this a new build? Have you added hardware?

Comment: There was no new hardware added to it, The monitor works fine. I am using it at the moment with another PC. It's an Acer M1640. Acer built it. The mobo doesnt even beep.

Comment: If you can't even get into the BIOS there's an issue that is out of your power. Are you still within the limits of your warranty?

Comment: Nope, its expired. You mean the PSU? What's wrong with the whole thing?

Comment: It's difficult to say. Seeing as you've tried bypassing the graphics card by plugging directly into the motherboard, then the motherboard is part of the issue. However, it could be that the PSU is now faulty and can't give enough power to bootstrap the whole system. If you have a multimeter handy you could test the PSU.

Comment: Errms, when I plug a USB into the mobo the USB flashes meaning theres life on the mobo. I dont think I have a spare PSU. I have a spare PSU however the pins dont fit.

Comment: There could be enough power to get the USB up and running, but bringing a whole system up requires a good deal more. I've been in situations where my fans would all light up and my drives would spin but my computer would get to the BIOS. It was a power supply issue. You could borrow a PSU from a friend and give it a try (make sure the powers either match up or the new one is more powerful). If not, you might benefit from spending 50$ and getting the computer tested at a computer shop. They would be able to tell you exactly what to do (assuming they're competent).

Comment: Ah oks, I will try find a PSU. By the way, if the PSU connector pins dont fit however slots in. Should it work or not?

Comment: Some older motherboard have 20 pin connectors and the newer ones have 24 pins. If your other PSU doesn't fit it is probably an older one. Assuming that's what you meant. Oh and no, a 20 pin connector from the PSU will not work in a 24 pin motherboard.

Comment: What are the symptons if the mobo is dead?

Comment: It comepletely depends on what the underlying issue is. In this case, I feel that you PSU is the culprit. I can't tell you exact symptoms of a dying motherboard because they vary.

Comment: @MaxMAckie: You should put your comment about how much power a PSU needs to bring up a whole system as an answer.  I've never really thought about it, and found your comment enlightening.

Comment: It depends on what your system is comprised of. If you have a large system with dual graphics cards, LED fans, blacklights and several hard drives you might need close to 1000 watts to bring it all up. Generally, you should be set with 500-600 watts.

Comment: Try another power cord, I have seen them go bad, rare but does happen. Try another electrical outlet, it it is connected to a power strip or other device, plug it directly into the wall socket.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but I'll answer anyway

This normally happens when the PSU's "PG" signal is no longer grounded, which normally means a faulty PSU.
A PSU tester can confirm whether that is the fact. If it is, then it's time for a PSU replacement.